# Free memory after Vacuum full?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, vacuum

I am running out of disk space on my database server. I have never executed a `vacuum full` and I'm hoping that `vacuum full` will free some space.

Have you run `vacuum full` before, and if space was freed up, how much was it?

Comment: You might want to have a look at tools like [pg_squeeze](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_squeeze) or [pg_repack](http://reorg.github.io/pg_repack/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

physically vacuum full makes a copy of table and destroys an old one. This leads to several conclusions:

- if you are low on space you might be not able to run it
- you will release as much space as it is taken by deleted tuples

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html

> This method also requires extra disk space, since it writes a new copy
>   of the table and doesn't release the old copy until the operation is
>   complete. Usually this should only be used when a significant amount
>   of space needs to be reclaimed from within the table.

You can find out the size of your data without gaps, by taking restoring  copy of it, eg `pg_dump`/`pg_restore`

Comment: Do you know how to determine the size of the deleted tuples?

Comment: the simplest is `pg_dump/restore` db somewhere. or for table individually `create table as select*`.